# XSD Schema restriction - prohibit specific character pair in the string

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I'm looking for a way to restrict character pair denoting an unicode character from appearing in the resulting XML. This character pair is  &# (for example &#xBB) . I'm trying to create a pattern in the XSD schema - to match if such character pair (&#) appear anywhere in the XML file. If such pair appears then the XML validation should fail . The restriction should also take into account the fact that the minimum string length equals to 1 and maximum to 79.

I've been trying to use following regex patternvalue="[^&#]{1,79}" but it does not work as expected. XML by design are encoded in the ISO-8859-2 format so any kind of unicode entries are not permitted.

What is the correct regex to establish such restriction ?

Thank You in advance. Jack

Answer (score 0):

The data that XML Schema sees and validates is the data AFTER expansion of entity and character references. So if the XML file contains `&#xBB;` then what the schema processor sees is `»`. You cannot in XSD ban `&#xBB;` without also banning `»`.

Comment: The thing is I just want to ban everything that is starting with &# - does the XML processor expand such data to "double right-angled quotation mark" if the encoding in the prologue is set to iso-8859-2 ?

Comment: Yes it does. Entity expansion and encoding are completely unrelated. First the bytes are decoded to characters using the approproiate encoding; then entity/character references in the sequence of characters are detected and expanded; then XSD validation is applied.

Comment: Speaking other words is there a pattern that will reject all unicode characters and treat all ISO-8859-2 characters as valid ? Obviosuly I can list all the characters that are allowed in my pattern (positive match) but I've a strange feeling that there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: Exaample: <TextLine>one, two, three></TextLine> should be treated as valid, <TextLine>one, two, &#xBB;, three </TextLine> should be treated as invalid and the entire XML should be rejected because &xBB does not have a representation in the ISO-8859-2 character set.

Comment: You'll just have to construct a regex that matches all the characters in ISO-8859-2. Shouldn't be too difficult.